# Cassandra prepared batch statement in datastax driver

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have used the below code for batch preparedstatement in Datastax java driver.

```
PreparedStatement ps = session.prepare("INSERT INTO messages (user_id,                                                                      
msg_id, title, body) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
BatchStatement batch = new BatchStatement();
batch.add(ps.bind(uid, mid1, title1, body1));
batch.add(ps.bind(uid, mid2, title2, body2));
batch.add(ps.bind(uid, mid3, title3, body3));
session.execute(batch);
```

Is this BatchStatement is logged or not logged?

Answer (score 5):

With no arguments, the BatchStatement() creates a logged batch.

Alternatively pass a BatchStatement.Type = UNLOGGED to create an UNLOGGED batch.

For details, check the docs: http://www.datastax.com/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/BatchStatement.html